# How to send image array to controller using ajax?

Tags: html, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Purpose: convert image array items to input list and send to controller.

Here is my JS code that select and modify images :

```
    const output = document.querySelector("output");
    const input = document.getElementById("roUpload");
    let imagesArray = [];

    input.addEventListener("change", () => {
      const files = input.files
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        imagesArray.push(files[i]);
      }
      displayImages();
    })

    function displayImages() {
      let images = ""
      imagesArray.forEach((image, index) => {
        images += `<div class="image">
                    <img src="${URL.createObjectURL(image)}" alt="image">
                    <span onclick="deleteImage(${index})">&times;</span>
                  </div>`
      })
      output.innerHTML = images;

    }
```

And this codes for sending to controller :

```
     var fileData = FormData();

     function SendImage(){

            **var files = output.files;**

            for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append("files", files[i]);
              }

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ChinaProblemsReport/SendImage/",
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                processData: false,
                data: fileData,
            });

            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                    window.location.reload();
            });
    };
```

Also here is html codes :

```
<input type="file" id="roUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg" />

<output></output>
```

I have not any problem to sending to controller, my problem is just How I can fill files(in `SendImage()`)
with **output** images?

Thanks if helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the `src` values:

```
            //getting the images inside output
            var files = output.querySelectorAll('img');
            var sources = [];

            for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
                sources.push(files[i].src);
            }
            fileData.append("files", sources);
```

This is untested, so it's possible that you will encounter a problem while testing. If so, let me know what the error was.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253461/discussion-on-answer-by-lajos-arpad-how-to-send-image-array-to-controller-using); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.